# Looping through Base64 txt files for bulk conversion to images?

Tags: python, base64

I have a large number of txt files that contain the base64 encoding for image files. Each txt file has a single encoding line starting with `"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/........."`. I got the following to work as far as saving the image:

```py
import base64
import os
import fnmatch

os.chdir(r'D:\Users\dubs\slidesets'):)
with open('data.image.jpeg.0bac61939da0c.txt', 'r') as file:
     str = file.read().replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '')
     print str
picname = open("data.image.jpeg.0bac61939da0c.jpg", "wb")
picname.write(str.decode('base64'))
picname.close()
```

My end goal would be to look in a directory for any txt file with "jpeg" in the name, get and edit the string from it, change to image, and save the image in the same directory with the same filename (`'data.image.jpeg.0bff54917a8c7.txt'` to `'data.image.jpeg.0bff54917a8c7.jpg'`).

```py
import fnmatch
import os
import base64

os.chdir(r'D:\Users\dubs\slidesets')
for file in os.listdir(r'D:\Users\dubs\slidesets')
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, "*jpeg*.txt"):
        newname = os.path.basename(file).replace(".txt", ".jpg")
        with open(file, 'r') as file:
            str = file.read().replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '')
        picname = open("newname", "wb")
        picname.write(str.decode('base64'))
        picname.close()
```

The error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I tried "newname" 'newname' and newname because I was unsure how that works with a variable instead, but that didn't help. Not sure why it works for one file in my top code but not in the loop?

Comment: What string is in `str = file.read()`

Comment: I think you should focus on getting a single file to work before worrying about doing bulk conversions...

Comment: @nauer This solved the problem for me with getting a single file to work. I had actually checked this before, but nothing was printing, so I actually thought I was not checking it correctly. After you confirmed that was the way to check, I opened the file back up. Blank. In my initial attempts, I must have deleted everything in the file somehow (luckily they are just copies).

Comment: @martineau I agree. This is new stuff to me, and I'm sure you all aren't fond of people jumping into a new language instead of starting at the absolute basic and moving up from there. I am teaching and the pictures are microscope slides, passed down in that form. I figured I would also struggle at the loop part as it is presumably the most complex part, so thought it would be better than cluttering with multiple posts.

Comment: Caleb: From you other comments it sound like you've got it working for a single file,  so I suggest you update your question accordingly — as there are definitely some issues with the code currently in the last snippet which is  attempting to process all the files in the given directory.

Comment: There is no need per se to `os.chdir()` anywhere; you are looping over absolute file names anyway. Changing the working directory of the process is harmless but entirely superfluous here.